# Unable to cast object of type WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[Models.AddonBatch,System.DateTime] to type System.IConvertible

Tags: c#, linq, razor, max, min

I am having trouble to get this LINQ query working.

I have in my Razor View a model, that contains few column and one of column is a list of items called Trans, inside Trans I have few columns, example

```
model { ID, Name, Email, Trans { ID, PostingDate, Amount}, Date}
```

I would like to get the MIN and MAX date of column postingDate, I tried this:

```
DateTime dateFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(Model.Select(d => d.Trans.Min(b => b.PostingDate)));
```

or

```
DateTime dateTo = Convert.ToDateTime(Model.Select(d => d.addonTrans.Select(t => t.PostingDate)).Max());
```

But none of then worked.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
DateTime dateFrom = models
    .SelectMany(d => d.Trans)
    .Select(tr => Convert.ToDateTime(tr.PostingDate))
    .Min();

DateTime dateTo = models
    .SelectMany(d => d.Trans)
    .Select(tr => Convert.ToDateTime(tr.PostingDate))
    .Max();
```

If the type of `PostingDate` is already a `DateTime`, you don't need the `Convert` call:

```
DateTime dateFrom = models
    .SelectMany(d => d.Trans)
    .Min(tr => tr.PostingDate);
```